# tmap place logo in a multiple map template

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to place the logo to the bottom right of the template on the same row as the legend   but the code below place it above each of the images:

```
library('raster')
library('scales')
library('tmap')

setwd('C:/WORK/')


idx <- seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2010/1/8"), '1 day')
r <- raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
rmap <- stack(lapply(1:length(idx), function(x) setValues(r, values = sample(x = c(-5:5),size = ncell(r), replace = T))))
rmap[is.na(rmap[])] <- 0 
rmap <- setZ(rmap, idx)
plot(rmap)
rmap

download.file("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png", "C:/WORK/logo.png", mode = "wb")

brks <- round(seq(-5, 5, by=((1))))
brks
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("azure","lightblue","blue","blue4","purple","pink")) # RFHAVG
col <- colfunc(length(brks)+1)
show_col(col)
labels <- paste0(brks,'-',brks[-1])[-length(brks)]
labels


plot <- tm_shape(rmap) +
  tm_raster(style = 'fixed', breaks =brks, palette = col,labels = labels,legend.is.portrait = FALSE) +
  tm_layout(main.title = 'test',
            main.title.size = 1,
            main.title.position = c("left", "top"),
            legend.outside.position = 'bottom',
            legend.position = c('center', 0.7),
            legend.outside.size = 0.35,
            legend.text.size = 0.7,
            legend.title.size = 0.01,
            legend.outside = T,
            frame=F) +
  tm_facets(nrow=2) +
  tm_logo('C:/WORK/logo.png') +
  tmap_options(check.and.fix = T)
plot
```

Can anybody help?